# Validating Bootstrap date-time picker in Laravel request

Tags: php, laravel, validation, date

I am using Bootstrap datetime picker and I am trying to validate the date in my controller but it always gives me an error saying the format is not right!.

However I can create a new Carbon date object from the request data just fine but I cannot validate the request object using the same format.

This throws an error saying the from does not match format `d M Y - H:i`

```
$request->validate([
            'from' => 'date_format:"d M Y - H:i"|required|before:till',
            'till' => 'date_format:"d M Y - H:i"|required|after:from'
    ]);
```

But this code works, if I use the data without any validation.

```
$ride->from = Carbon::createFromFormat('d M Y - H:i', $request->from)->toDateTimeString();
$ride->till = Carbon::createFromFormat('d M Y - H:i', $request->till)->toDateTimeString();
```

*Note*: 
The bootstrap dateTimePicker has `format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii"` but I understand javascript format differs from php format.

*What is going wrong here?*

**Edit:** These are the input dates obtained from dumping the request object.

```
  "from" => "16 November 2017 - 14:10"
  "till" => "06 November 2017 - 12:00"
```

Comment: Show the input dates that are passed to validator.

Comment: @LeszekRepie added, please see the edit

Comment: Display datetime in php with this format and check if it is the same. You should see "15 November 2017 - 15:40"  (time will be diff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because using `before` and `after` for date is goes to strtotime for checking check this in [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-before)

And `16 Nov 2017 - 12:10` is not valid date check [not valid date](https://eval.in/901483) Also check after removing `-` [valid date](https://eval.in/901488)

So I suggest you to convert like this

```
$from = str_replace("-","",$request->from);
$to = str_replace("-","",$request->to);
$request->validate([
        'from' => 'date_format:"d M Y - H:i"|required|before:'.$to,
        'till' => 'date_format:"d M Y - H:i"|required|after:'.$from
]);
```

Comment: I tried your solution and but I still get the error.                                       
 ```The from does not match the format d M Y - H:i.
The till does not match the format d M Y - H:i.```

Comment: May be it's `till` I took `to` try with `till` with your data

Answer (score 0):

To be honest you don't need to watch the date formats. Totally unnecessary. I suggest you do something like this:

```
$fromDate = Carbon::parse($request->get('from'));
$toDate = Carbon::parse($request->get('to'));
```

Now the above will allow you to compare the dates for conditions such as:

- Check whether you have passed a valid date.
- Start date should not be greater than to date.
- To Date should not be less than start date.

Then you can do something like:

```
if (($startDate === false) || ($toDate === false)) {
    // return error
}

// Check start date is greater than to date
if ($startDate->gt($toDate)) {
}

// Check to date is not less than to date
if ($toDate->lt($toDate)) {
}
```

As long as you are passing date in a correct format, this should be enough. No need for you to do validation on date format.

Comment: I know I can do it outside of validation method but that defeats the purpose and I mainly want to check the `before` and `after` conditions. Validation provides much better and elegant solutions rather than using if else loop.

Comment: Yes it does. But building validation rules on the fly sometime is necessary.